# Azure cognitive services - Computer vision working, Image moderation doesn't

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I tested my subscribtion key in the API Console, the computer vision part is working fine, but the Image moderation API says that my subscription key is not valid. I tried to re-generate my keys, but that also failed me.

Comment: Did you get a key for Content Moderation?  Each service requires its own API key and are not interchangeable.

Comment: As I know, the content moderation and image analyzer requires the same key, which is the one given by the azure cognitive services resource. I used this combination once, with the same subscription key, but now it didn't want to work for me. :(

Comment: They require different API keys because they are separate services with separate quotas and rate limits. What you are describing should have never worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, the Computer Vision and Content Moderator (of which Image Moderation is part) services had different mechanism for provisioning API keys.  You were required to use different keys for each.

While that option remains available, the good news is that unified keys were recently [launched](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/) and now you can get one API key that will work across a slew of Cognitive Services instead.

With unified keys you have fewer pricing options, so you may still prefer to use the per-service API key.